# Setting up Google Merchant Wallet for IAP?

Tags: java, android

I've been Googling all over the place for this but I can't find an answer. Do I have to own a legal business to set up a merchant wallet? Is it okay if I use my home address? And should I put my developer name down for "credit card statement name"? And is it okay if I use my own developer email for "customer support email"? I know this isn't a programming question per se, but I just really need an answer from someone who knows this stuff.

Comment: What did you do? I'm struggling for same stuff